# The Composer installer script did not run correctly [exit code 1]

Tags: composer-php

I tried to install Composer-php in Windows 10 by downloading the executable Composer-Setup.exe from getcomposer. When prompted during installation to chose the command-line PHP I wanted to use, I entered my path to PHP C:\WinNMP\bin\PHP\64bit-php-7.4\php.exe

But I got following error:

```
Script Output: PHP Warning: realpath(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
```

File(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\is-1KBL9.tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (c:/winnmp) in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\is-1KBL9.tmp\installer.php on line 655 PHP Warning: is_writeable(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\is-1KBL9.tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (c:/winnmp) in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\is-1KBL9.tmp\installer.php on line 657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `php.ini` places restrictions on which directories are accessible with the [`open_basedir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) option:

> Limit the files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified directory-tree, including the file itself. [...]
>
> When a script tries to access the filesystem, for example using include, or fopen(), the location of the file is checked.

You can run `php -i` to find out where your `php.ini` is located and then either disable/modify that option, e.g. make sure that `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp` is accessible.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I just commented #open_basedir = "c:/winnmp" in php.ini and reinstalled Composer-php

Answer (score 0):

In 90% of cases, the problem is the Windows Firewall

Turn off the Windows Defender Firewall when installing

Comment: Worked, Thanks alot

Answer (score -1):

In 90% of cases, the problem is the Windows Firewall. Turn off the Windows Defender Firewall when installing.

Answer (score -2):

I disabled my firewall and solved this composer problem:

Script Output:
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for getcomposer.org failed: No such host is known.

Comment: Please share more details. The error message you are facing looks completely different than the one from the question